# running nunit tests from visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit

Ive just installed Nunit V3.7.1 and Im trying to actually run my tests.  Previously Id used the GUi but this only seems to be avaibale as a 'beta' version.  Ive installed the 0.4 preview version and pointed it to my c# test project (.net 4.5) and the run state is set as 'NotRunnable' - _SKIPREASON = File type is not supported.  How can I run my tests using nunit v3.7.1 ?  I dont want to run (& debug) all my tests everytime, only selected tets (this was easy with mstest).  Should I switch back to the previous version of Nunit ?

Answer (score 2):

The NUnit project offers a so-called Test Adapter. It's a Visual Studio plugin for full integration of the test suite (of the former GUI which you already know) into the IDE.

You can find it on the website of NUnit -> Downloads http://nunit.org/download/, NUnit Test Adapter x.x -> https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/releases/download/3.8/NUnit3TestAdapter-3.8.0.vsix.

After installing it, you can run all/specific/failed NUnit tests directly out of Visual Studio (see top navigation with lable "Test").

The plugin also works in the 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Ive decided to use XUnit instead, it comes with a test explorer, I got it up and running in a few minutes, which wasnt the case with Nunit :-(

Comment: Well, you actually asked for an explanation of how to run existing NUnit tests. As I stated there is a solution which also provides seemless integration into the IDE, so you can use the test explorer of visual studio. From my point I gave an answer to your particular question. Additionally, why should you use a dedicated GUI? With the VSIX-plugin you can seemlessly run and debug your test cases like you can with MSTest. I honestly advice you to try the solution I gave you.